# Solving $\left(\sin\left(\sqrt{x}+5\right)-\cos\left(\sqrt{x}+5\right)\right)e^\sqrt{x}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I tried to solve the following problem; but I couldn't.

$$\left(\;\sin\left(\sqrt{x}+5\right)-\cos\left(\sqrt{x}+5\right)\;\right)e^\sqrt{x}=0$$

I placed it into [Microsoft Math Solver](https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/en/solve-problem/%60left(%20%20%60sin%20(%20%20%20%60sqrt%7B%20x%20%20%7D%20%20%2B5%20%20%20)%20%20-%20%60cos%20(%20%20%20%60sqrt%7B%20x%20%20%7D%20%20%2B5%20%20%20)%20%20%20%20%60right)%20%20%20%7B%20e%20%20%7D%5E%7B%20%20%60sqrt%7B%20x%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%3D%20%200) and the following was the answer:

$$x=\frac{(-4\pi n_1+20-9\pi)^2}{16}, n_1\in Z$$

How do I solve it to reach the correct answer?

**My solution**:

$$\sin(\sqrt{x}+5)=\cos(\sqrt{x}+5)$$

$$\sqrt{x}+5=\pi n_1+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

And after solving it I obtained:

$$x=\frac{(4\pi n_1-20+\pi)^2}{16}$$

My solution lacks the **$9$** that there's in the correct answer.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: hint: $9\pi = \pi + 2(4\pi)$

Answer (score 6):

Your answer is equivalent to the one given. In particular, we have
$$
\frac{(4\pi n_1-20+\pi)^2}{16} = \\
\frac{(-4\pi n_1+20-\pi)^2}{16} = \\
\frac{(-4\pi[n_1-2 + 2]+20-\pi)^2}{16} =\\
\frac{(-4\pi[n_1-2] - 8\pi+20-\pi)^2}{16} =\\
\frac{(-4\pi[n_1-2]+20-9\pi)^2}{16}.
$$

Answer (score 6):

You are correct.
$n_1$ is just an arbitrary integer.

You can rewrite, $\boxed{(-4\pi n_1 +20 - 9\pi ) ^2}= (4\pi n_1 + 9\pi - 20)^2 = (4\pi n_1 + 8\pi + \pi - 20)^2 = \boxed{(4\pi n + \pi -20)^2}$

where $n = n_1 +2$

Answer (score 0):

We need

$$-4m\pi+20-9\pi=\pm(4\pi n-20+\pi)$$

Considering the '-' sign, $$-4m\pi+20-9\pi=-(4\pi n-20+\pi)$$

$$\iff-4m-9=-4n-1 \iff4n=4m+8\iff n=m+2$$

Clearly, we don't need to consider the $+$ sign (why?)